# PTTH or Reverse Http to/from Apple TV

Tags: c#, apple-tv

I've been trying to get the [event connection](http://nto.github.io/AirPlay.html#servicediscovery-airplayservice) running to/from my Apple TV for some time but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I write my request and I get the proper response. But I do not get any events when I pause or when the video stops.

The relevant code for the event connection is as follow:

```
var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.13.37"), 23579);
var socket = new Socket(endpoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Bind(endpoint);
socket.Connect("192.168.13.13", 7000);
socket.NoDelay = true;

var request = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("POST /Reverse HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nUpgrade: PTTH/1.0\r\nX-Apple-Purpose: event\r\nUser-Agent: ItsMe/5.7\r\nX-Apple-Session-ID: f519e023-da6d-4fc2-902f-791c07dd9ff8\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n");
socket.Send(request, request.Length, 0);

var response = new Byte[4096];
var read = socket.Receive(response, response.Length, 0);
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response, 0, read);
```

Response from Apple TV:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2012 17:33:41 GMT
Upgrade: PTTH/1.0
Connection: Upgrade
```

My first tries I closed the socket at this point and started a `TcpListener` (also tried `HttpListener`). All three approaches have been totally fruitless, just to be complete I'll include my current code (that does not work). I am currently back to `TcpListener`:

```
socket.Disconnect(true);
socket.Close();

var listener = new TcpListener(lep);
listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = true;
listener.Start();

while (true)
{
    var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()))
    {
        while (isRunning)
        {
            if (reader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
    client.Close();
}
```

I am not planning to keep the `while (true)` but until I get events and can know when the video stops playing I have nothing else to put there.

I do this part first then I send a `play` command with a URL to a file on my machine and it starts playing on the Apple TV just fine. I alos can send `scrub` commands and get info back about Position/Duration but no events what so ever.

Any help/suggestions is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you make false assumptions about how the Connection works:

- You client sends a UPGRADE to the AirPlay-Server.
- The AirPlay-Server answers with 101 on that connection *and abandones it*
- The AirPlay-Server initiates a new connection with your client. It will use HTTP for that
- Your client answers with 200 or whatever.

You will probably need an opened http-listener, before you post your UPGRADE request, to handle incoming events.

See here for reference: http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-lentczner-rhttp-00.txt

Comment: My main app is a web server that serves the videos but according to my logs I do not get any events there neither. When I used Wireshark and start a video from iTunes I can see the event data on a random(?) port. What I am looking for is information on how the ATV decides what port to communicate events on.

Comment: So your webserver sends the upgrade?
And it does not receive anything from the ATV on port 80 (webserver port 80; the ATV port should be random, cause it makes a http connect to the soruce of the upgrade)?

Comment: My main app is just a self hosted server with a catch all route on ports 80, 8080 and some others (for testing). I serve the video files this way (unless the play command is for a file on the web) and currently I log all requests (method, path, etc). It's catch all as I use the path and querystring to identify videos. In the log I get no /event requests, which led me to assume the upgrade was using the actual connection made for it but in reverse. Googled server software seems to support this assumption.

Comment: Since your Connection (for the upgrage) is HTTP based, it will end with the Response. It's no Long poll or something like that - your client changes the role and get's a server, which has to handle the /event calls.
Perhaps you try to reduce the complexity for testing purposes by openening an http listener, then sending the upgrade and controlling the ATV manually? Also use the wireshark and perhaps post what you see there..